# Why is not std::swap in global namespace?

Tags: c++, swap

Item 25 in [Effective c++ third edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876), Scott Meyers suggests to implement swap in the same namespace as the class, and then when swapping to employ the using std::swap, and there the author says :

> For example, if you were to write the call to swap this way:
>
> ```
> std::swap(obj1,obj2);  // the wrong way to call swap
> ```
>
> you'd force the compiler to consider only the swap in std, thus
>   eliminating the possibility of getting a more appropriate T-specific
>   version defined elsewhere. Alas, some misguided programmers do qualify
>   calls to swap in this way, and that is why it's important to totally
>   specialize std::swap for your classes.

The author recommends to always swap objects this way :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

#define CUSTOM_SWAP

namespace aaa{

struct A
{
};
#ifdef CUSTOM_SWAP
void swap( A&, A& )
{
    std::cout<<"not std::swap"<<std::endl;
}
#endif

}

int main() 
{
    using std::swap;   // add std::swap to a list of possible resolutions

    aaa::A a1;
    aaa::A a2;

    swap(a1,a2);
}
```

Why isn't `std::swap` in global namespace? That way, it would be simpler to add custom swap functions.

Comment: Because it would step in your way when you wouldn't want it to?

Comment: @jrok Ok, I guess it would step in the way when you implement templates. Right?

Comment: Or not. Suppose you wanted to call your own global `swap` for some concrete type and expect to fail to compile if some other type were passed. With a `swap` template in global scope, it would compile anyway.

Comment: @jrok How could it introduce problems? What are cases you wouldn't want swap to be in the global namespace? Can you think of an example?

Comment: @BЈовић the programmer might want to define his own `swap` function (or class, or variable) in the global namespace. It could cause problems in the same way that putting anything else in the globla namespace could. There is a reason why the standard library stays within the `std` namespace. :)

Comment: One more thing: If "never write `std::swap˙(x,y);`" is the lesson you learned from Meyers' article, then I dare to say it's a wrong lesson. If you *know* you want to call `std::swap`, then by all means, call it explicitly.

Comment: @jrok Someone using my class may not be aware there is a specialized swap for it. Anyway, catscradle answered my question in comments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably because the standard says so, 17.6.1.1/2:

> All library entities except macros, operator new and operator delete are deﬁned within the namespace std or namespaces nested within namespace std.

And you would still need to put `using ::swap` sometimes, so it would introduce even more special cases. Here I use `func` instead of `swap` - http://ideone.com/WAWBfZ :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
auto func(T) -> void
{
cout << "::f" << endl;
}

namespace my_ns {
struct my_struct {};

auto func(my_struct) -> void
{
cout << "my_ns::func" << endl;
}

auto another_func() -> void
{
// won't compile without `using ::func;`
func(123);
}
}

auto main() -> int {}
```

fails with

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘void my_ns::another_func()’:
prog.cpp:21:17: error: could not convert ‘123’ from ‘int’ to ‘my_ns::my_struct’
         func(123);
```

Comment: Upvote because a "bitchslap with the standard" is always nice to see.

Comment: My question is really : why the standard says that swap should be in the std namespace

Comment: @BЈовић `swap` is a part of standard library. Why make it a special case then?

Comment: According to Scott Meyers, you should always put `using std::swap`. That is why.

Comment: @BЈовић This idiom used when you write generic template code. The idea is to use specialized `swap` functions for the types that provide it (because it's presumably optimized for their case) and fall back on `std::swap` otherwise. The code in OP is not that great an example.

Comment: @BЈовић You would still need to put `using ::swap` sometimes, so it would introduce even more special cases. Here I use `func` instead of `swap` - http://ideone.com/WAWBfZ.